# What's the cleanest way to obtain the IP address from net/http.Request.RemoteAddr

Tags: http, go

Golang net/http library provides a [Request struct](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request),
which is the object returned when running a server.

The struct includes RemoteAddr: string.

This contains both the remote (client) IP address and client port number. It can be IPv4 or IPv6 of course.

An IPv6 example value seen (when the client is on the local host) is:

```
"[::1]:53947"
```

An IPv4 example is:

```
"127.0.0.1:54572"
```

Are there library functions to decompose these into host and port, or is it necessary to use string manipulations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [net.SplitHostPort](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#SplitHostPort):

```
func main() {
  host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort("[::1]:53947")
  fmt.Println(host)
  host, _, _ = net.SplitHostPort("127.0.0.1:54572")
  fmt.Println(host)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BuQRhD0sL54

Since all you need is the host, you can `_` the port. If you ever need to go the other way, there's also [net.JoinHostPort](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#JoinHostPort).

Comment: Thank you. The reason this was not obvious to me, is that the split function belongs to the `net` library. I was looking for it down in `net/http`. Makes sense now.